# Showing a countable set is not compact.

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, compactness

I was wondering if what I have done is correct.

Show that the set is not compact using the open cover definition (i.e., a subset $A$ of a metric space $\mathbb{X}$ is compact if every open cover of $A$ has a finite subcover).

$$A=\left\{\left(n, \frac{1}{n}\right):n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R^{2}}$$

$A$ is an open cover for itself. Suppose that the finite subcover $$B=\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}\left\{\left(n,\frac{1}{n}\right)\right\}\subseteq\mathbb{R^{2}}$$ contains $A$. But since the point $\left(k+1,\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\in A$ and the point $\left(k+1,\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\notin B$, then $A\nsubseteq B$, so B is an open cover without a finite subcover of A. Thus, A is not compact.

If it is correct, it seems like using open countable sets (of only one variable?) as their own open covers is the easiest way to do these problems. But, I also haven't thought of any examples where this wouldn't work or would be harder, so if someone could provide examples, then I would appreciate it.

Comment: Err … assuming $(n,1/n)$ is meant to be a pair, $A$ is not open (at least when using the standard topology on $\mathbb R^2$). But then, in that case your definition of $B$ doesn't really make sense, as a pair of real numbers is not a set of real numbers. So maybe that notation is meant to be something different? Also note that, at least in the standard topology, a non-empty countable set never can be open.

Comment: @MattAPelto, yes it was meant as a subset of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$.

Comment: @celtschk, the set $A$ is supposed to be the union of those points in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ I think. And $B$ is supposed to be the finite union of those points in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$. Sorry I did not make that as clear as I thought. I will edit it.

Comment: $A$ still is not an open set, and in particular not an open cover of itself.

Comment: @MattAPelto, thanks. But why is $A$ closed? I thought $A$ wouldn't be closed because even though it is the union of singleton points in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$, it doesn't contain all of it's accumulation points (I'm thinking of as $n$ goes to infinity, but I am not sure if we can consider that an accumulation point because the first component isn't finite, while the second component goes to $0$).

Comment: @Jake: $A$ doesn't have an accumulation point as the sequence of points doesn't converge as $n\to\infty$ (the first component, $n$, diverges). Note, however, that even if $A$ were a non-closed countable set, it still wouldn't be open (as can be seen e.g. by the fact that it doesn't contain an open ball around $(2,1/2)\in A$).

Comment: "But why is A closed?"  No-one said A was closed.  It is not closed.  But it sure as heck is not open either.  *Lots* of sets are neither open nor closed.

Comment: @fleablood: $A$ is closed. You're right that at that point nobody had claimed that it is, though.

Comment: Yes, $A \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ is closed because its closure equals itself ($\bar{A}=A$). So either all limit points of $A$ belong to $A$ or no point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a limit point of $A$. As celtschk previously noted, $A$ has no limit points and so it is closed (in a trivial, yet slightly counterintuitive sense).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have that $A$ is a collection of points. Here you would argue that $A$ is not compact by considering the open cover $B(a_n, 1)$, where $a_n =(n, \frac{1}{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^2$   $(n=1, 2, \ldots)$.

Comment: While $A$ is closed, it is not true that all countable subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ are closed. For example, the equally countable subset $B=\{(1/n,0)|n\in\mathbb Z^+\}\subset \mathbb R^2$ is *not* closed.

Comment: I edited things so that there would be no confusion. Before editing, I gave my original post an honest read and thought it was still clear that I was saying pointsets are closed. Clearly I would not mean to imply any arbitrary collection of pointsets because people could literally consider the collection of all points in any space where a notion of pointset actually applies.

Comment: Of course $A$ is not a collection of pointsets (or a collection of sets at all), but a collection of points (that is, a subset of $\mathbb R^2$). Maybe you meant a countable *union* of pointsets? But then, we've got a shorter name for that: A countable set. While a pointset is closed, I don't see how this is relevant here.

Comment: Actually I don't understand your second paragraph at all. What are the open intervals you are talking about?

Comment: Ah, so you are **reinterpreting** the pairs to denote open intervals. Well, in that case you should be more explicit of that, because it is **not at all** clear what you are doing there.

Comment: Looking at page 143, example 6 of *Topology* by James R Munkres. I actually think the OP has their question written correctly.